# C++ Find the biggest number with deque?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So I'm having some troubles with pointers and the more I try to google it - the more confused I get since most explanations are either too simple or too complicated that I can apply it to my task at hand.

What I am trying to do is have a deque of 20 random numbers (int) and then have a function find the biggest one of those but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

int *findBiggest(int *nQ, int platser)
{
    deque<int> *p;
    int* test;
    int big=0;
    for(int i=0; i<platser; i++)
    {
        test = nQ.front();
        cout << "Place[" << i << "]: \t" << test << endl;
        nQ.pop_front();
        if(test > big)
            big = test;
    }
    cout << "\nThe biggest number is: " << big << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    deque <int> nQ;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        nQ.push_back(rand() % 10000);
    }
    findBiggest(nQ, 20);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be apprechiated!

Comment: How this is related to c# and asp.net ?

Comment: start with `int *nQ,` -> `deque<int>& nQ,`

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you getting an error?  Are you getting a result you don't expect?  Have you run it in the debugger and watch the variables to see where the issue is?

Comment: You may use `std::max_element`.

Comment: Why are you using pointers at all?

Comment: @Piotr S. That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user3585278: posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your declaration:

```
int *findBiggest(int *nQ, int platser)
```

should be:

```
int *findBiggest(deque<int>& nQ, int platser)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you're looking for?

```
template<typename forwardItr_>
auto get_max_value(forwardItr_ beg, forwardItr_ end) -> decltype(*beg) 
{
    auto biggest = *beg;
    while(beg != end) {
        if(biggest < *beg)
            biggest = *beg;
        ++beg;
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to C++ and haven't used decltype so this was not exactly what I was looking for, and I couldn't seem to make it work with this code.

Comment: The decltype() is a type deduction keyword that takes an expression and deduces the type at compile time, this is handy since this function will work for any type assuming the type has operator*  and operator< implemented, the return type doesn't need to be modified since the decltype will deduce the type to return by checking the deferenced type of beg. you can call this function in your code as so:

std::cout << get_max_value(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.end());

I thought you were only looking for a function to find the maximum value of a container.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

int *findBiggest(deque<int>& nQ, int places)
{
    int test;
    int big=0;
    for(int i=0; i<places; i++)
    {
        test = nQ.front();
        cout << "Place[" << i << "]: \t" << test << endl;
        nQ.pop_front();
        if(test > big)
            big = test;
    }
    cout << "\nThe biggest number is: " << big << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    deque <int> nQ;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        nQ.push_back(rand() % 10000);
    }
    findBiggest(nQ, 20);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```